# application only authentication twitter api android

Tags: android, search, twitter-oauth

Folks,

With the advent of Twitter 1.1 API, my single line query:

```
http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=@DCComics&rpp=25&page=1
```

No longer works. I would like to use Application Only Authentication via oAuth, but I can't say I've found any tutorials or samples to use to hepl me pound it out. I'm a relative newcomer to JAVA and Android development. Can someone offer up a code snippet or point me in a direction where I could find additional assistance?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I found a tutorial that walked me through both user and application authentication at

http://ttlnews.blogspot.com/2013/07/integrating-twitter-11-api-in-android.html

Answer (score 0):

This one is based on Twitter4j library which uses OAuth

https://github.com/swavkulinski/twitter-oauth-demo